# How to undo killing all entities on a server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I was setting up the command block system for my new Minecraft server, I started setting up the command which would destroy all dropped items, but I accidentally killed all entities! How can I undo this? Someone please help me.

Comment: There is now way to undo a command. Unless you have made a backup of your world you cannot recover the lost entities.

Answer (score 8):

**You can't**. Unless you have a recent backup to restore, this action is permanent. Next time, what I would do is test these sorts of systems in a backup of the world to begin with to try to spot any potential issues like this one, before implementing it on the live server.

Comment: On the plus side, unloaded chunks _should_ be unaffected.

Answer (score -1):

You can copy "entities" catalog from another world but you will lose all animals including villagers.